# How can I slice a string separated by "/"?

Tags: mysql

How can I slice a string that is separated by `/` ?

Example:

| id | column1 |
| --- | --- |
| 01 | x/pp/llllll |
| 02 | lll/k/uu/llll/nbbbb |
| 03 | zzzzzz/wwww/s/aa |

What I want is to return the first input up to the comma:

| id | column1 |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | x |
| 2 | lll |
| 3 | zzzzzz |

Comment: _..return the first input until the comma:.._ There is no comma but `/`. However the much much better approach is [normalization](https://www.guru99.com/database-normalization.html) instead of storing delimited lists.

Comment: `SUBSTRING_INDEX(collumn1, '/', 1)`

Answer (score 1):

The below statement should do the trick!

```
SELECT id, SUBSTRING_INDEX(column1, '/', 1) AS column1 
FROM [TableName];
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

Welcome! As B001ᛦ said, it might not be a good idea depending on your data.

To manipulate strings, look at the [String functions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html).

```sql
SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(column1, '/', 1) FROM foo;
```

SQL Fiddle : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2ff4f7

Answer (score -1):

Use regex

```
SELECT
  ID,
  REGEXP_REPLACE(column1, '/.*', '')
FROM …
```

See [live demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/sswnxNCyZAzjaPNktTWMpb/0).